# How to share events between forms

Tags: vb.net

So i have a tray icon that should behave the same way between 3 forms. I then created this code:

```
Private Sub TrayForm_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If Not Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of TrayForm).Any = 1 Then
            TrayForm.ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Which is used to handle the tray icon. How can i do to share this event between the forms so i don't have to place this same code on every form?

How are event handlers working exactly? I looked online and on MSDN and it is not clear to me.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to share code which is part of a control you need to subclass it. Then use it (the control) everywhere you want.

Comment: It is not obvious why it has to be "shared".  You only need *one* event handler that responds to the mouse click.  That invariably is also the form that contains the NotifyIcon component.  So "TrayForm" makes little sense, you use `Me`.

Comment: So i should use something like:     Protected Overridable Sub Trayiconclick(e As EventArgs)
        AddHandler TrayClick, AddressOf TrayForm_MouseClick
        RaiseEvent TrayClick(Me, e)
    End Sub ?  Also, the Trayform is used only to get the ToolStripMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to share the *event*, and not juste the code that will handle the event?

If you don't want to copy and paste your code, which you need to handle the events of more than one form, here's a way to do it:

Declare the sub which contains the code needed to handle the event as a public shared sub. Like this:

```
Public Shared Sub TrayForm_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
```

So, now you have a Sub which can handle the event you want to handle from all three forms.

Now, when you initialize those forms, add a line to make the shared Sub handle the event you want it to handle:

```
AddHandler NotifyIcon1.MouseClick, AddressOf ProjectName.FileName.TrayForm_MouseClick
```

*ProjectName.FileName* is meant here to be the path to refer to the shares Sub inside the file where you put it. I usually name it like *ProjectNameUtils.vb* or something like that.

If you just want to avoid copy and pasting your Sub so you don't have to modify it at several places every time you change something, this could be a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

As Stipulated by Hans Passant:

```
Sub Eclass_EventHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If Not Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of TrayForm).Any = 1 Then
            Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

On the Trayform.VB just did the trick.

But about the shared event. i Have one that would have to be:

```
Private Sub FormClosingEVENT(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If Not FromMenu Then e.Cancel = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    'Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

How should i handle this?

Comment: The OpenForms check is not necessary, you cannot click on the NotifyIcon without automatically closing the context menu.  No need for "sharing" the FormClosing event either, you are interested in keeping a *specific* form alive.  Surely the one that has the NotifyIcon.  It is not complete enough, you must add code that checks the e.CloseReason.  You never want to keep the form alive when the user, say, tries to shut down the OS.

Comment: This was an example that had not much to do with my code. Say for another example...     Private Sub FormClosing_event(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub   Finally, i just want to know how to share events between form.

Comment: Hmya, you keep coming up with examples where you most definitely do *not* want to share events.  It is exceeding rare to need to do so.

Comment: So i should just use the same events privately for all forms? Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it!